# Get currently pressed keys in inspector

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, unity3d-editor

I am currently building a simple shortcuts system for my Unity project.

At the moment I am inserting the shortcuts in the inspector by string, for example: "Control+Alt+A". but writing it every time is too annoying.

So I thought about creating a custom editor for it, where the textbox would be filled automatically with the keys the user presses. Unfortunately the only way I found about getting this info is with the OnSceneGUI function, but it requires the scene window to have focus, and if the shortcut is defined in Unity it would fire.

To sum up, How can I read the currently pressed keys and display them with an editor script¿

Edit: [this link](https://forum.unity.com/threads/custom-inspector-to-capture-a-single-key-press.551566/) almost does what I need, but it detects only one key (no combinations), and the Shift key isn't detected at all

Comment: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Input.html

Comment: @BugFinder Not what I need

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depends a lot on how you store and check the hotkeys later but you could create a custom EditorWindow pop-up.

First I would store my shortcut e.g. like

```
[Serializable]
public struct ShortCut
{
    public bool Ctrl;
    public bool Alt;
    public bool Shift;

    public KeyCode Key;

    public ShortCut(KeyCode key, bool ctrl, bool alt, bool shift)
    {
        Key = key;
        Ctrl = ctrl;
        Alt = alt;
        Shift = shift;
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        var builder = new StringBuilder();
        if (Ctrl) builder.Append("CTRL + ");
        if (Alt) builder.Append("ALT + ");
        if (Shift) builder.Append("SHIFT + ");

        builder.Append(Key.ToString());

        return builder.ToString();
    }

    public bool IsDown => IsCtrlDown && IsAltDown && IsShiftDown && Input.GetKeyDown(Key);

    private bool IsCtrlDown => !Ctrl || Input.GetKey(KeyCode.RightControl) || Input.GetKey(KeyCode.LeftControl);
    private bool IsAltDown => !Alt || Input.GetKey(KeyCode.LeftAlt) || Input.GetKey(KeyCode.RightAlt);
    private bool IsShiftDown => !Shift || Input.GetKey(KeyCode.LeftShift) || Input.GetKey(KeyCode.RightShift);
}
```

You can wait for it in a script like e.g.

```
public class ShortCutTester : MonoBehaviour
{
    // This youc an now call via the context menu of the someShortCut field in the Inspector
    [ContextMenuItem("Set Shortcut", nameof(SetSomeShortCut))]
    public ShortCut someShortCut;

    private void SetSomeShortCut()
    {
        ShortKeyDialog.ShowDialog(someShortCut, result =>
        {
            // mark as dirty and provide undo/redo funcztionality
            Undo.RecordObject(this, "Change someShortCut");
            someShortCut = result;
        });
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        if (someShortCut.IsDown)
        {
            Debug.Log("Hello!");
        }
    }

    #if UNITY_EDITOR
    // in order to catch all editor own key events on runtime
    // you will still get the warning "You have to exit playmode in order to save"
    // but at least this makes the Hello print anyway. Couldn't figure out how to catch the key completely before Unity handles it
    private void OnGUI()
    {
        var e = Event.current;
        e.Use();
    }
    #endif
}
```

and set it via a popup dialog

```
public class ShortKeyDialog : EditorWindow
{
    private ShortCut keys;
    private ShortCut newKeys;
    private Action<ShortCut> callback;
    private bool changed;

    public static void ShowDialog( ShortCut currentShortcut, Action<ShortCut> onDone)
    {
        var dialog = GetWindow<ShortKeyDialog>();
        dialog.keys = currentShortcut;
        dialog.newKeys = currentShortcut;
        dialog.callback = onDone;
        dialog.minSize = new Vector2(300, 200);
        dialog.position = new Rect(Screen.width / 2f + 150, Screen.height / 2f + 100, 300, 200);
        dialog.ShowModalUtility();
    }

    private void OnGUI()
    {
        //Get pressed keys
        var e = Event.current;
        if (e?.isKey == true)
        {
            switch (e.type)
            {
                case EventType.KeyDown:
                    switch (e.keyCode)
                    {
                        // Here you will need all allowed keycodes
                        case KeyCode.A:
                        case KeyCode.B:
                        case KeyCode.C:
                        case KeyCode.D:
                        case KeyCode.E:
                        case KeyCode.F:
                        case KeyCode.G:
                        case KeyCode.H:
                        case KeyCode.I:
                        case KeyCode.J:
                        case KeyCode.K:
                        case KeyCode.L:
                        case KeyCode.M:
                        case KeyCode.N:
                        case KeyCode.O:
                        case KeyCode.P:
                        case KeyCode.Q:
                        case KeyCode.R:
                        case KeyCode.S:
                        case KeyCode.T:
                        case KeyCode.U:
                        case KeyCode.V:
                        case KeyCode.W:
                        case KeyCode.X:
                        case KeyCode.Y:
                        case KeyCode.Z:
                        case KeyCode.F1:
                        case KeyCode.F2:
                        case KeyCode.F3:
                        case KeyCode.F4:
                        case KeyCode.F5:
                        case KeyCode.F6:
                        case KeyCode.F7:
                        case KeyCode.F8:
                        case KeyCode.F9:
                        case KeyCode.F10:
                        case KeyCode.F11:
                        case KeyCode.F12:
                        case KeyCode.F13:
                        case KeyCode.F14:
                        case KeyCode.F15:
                        case KeyCode.Comma:
                        case KeyCode.Plus:
                        case KeyCode.Minus:
                        case KeyCode.Period:
                            // etc depends on your needs I guess
                            changed = true;
                            newKeys = new ShortCut (e.keyCode, e.control, e.alt, e.shift);

                            // Refresh the EditorWindow
                            Repaint();
                            break;
                    }
                    break;
            }

            // Use all key presses so nothing else handles them 
            // e.g. also not the Unity editor itself like e.g. for CTRL + S
            e.Use();
        }

        EditorGUILayout.LabelField("Current Shortcut");
        EditorGUILayout.HelpBox(keys.ToString(), MessageType.None);

        EditorGUILayout.Space();

        EditorGUILayout.LabelField("Press buttons to assign a new shortcut", EditorStyles.textArea);

        EditorGUILayout.HelpBox(newKeys.ToString(), MessageType.None);

        EditorGUILayout.Space();

        EditorGUILayout.BeginHorizontal();
        {
            if (GUILayout.Button("Cancel"))
            {
                Close();
            }
            EditorGUI.BeginDisabledGroup(!changed);
            {
                if (GUILayout.Button("Save"))
                {
                    callback?.Invoke(newKeys);
                    Close();
                }
            }
            EditorGUI.EndDisabledGroup();
        }
        EditorGUILayout.EndHorizontal();
    }
}
```

---

***Please note: Typed on smartphone so no chance to test and correct things currently but I hope the idea gets clear***

*Will test and update asap when back on a PC*

Comment: It works good, but I have 2 questions; 1) what is dialog.ShowModalUtility(), it doesn't compile.

2) Is there a way to cancel the shortcuts in Unity for that purpose, because shortcuts like Ctrl+S are also related to Unity

Comment: never mind, I have fixed those issues with the script I linked in my question. I would update my question to include the correct and full code ASAP.

Thank you very much, you always give the best an d most detailed answers

Comment: Hey I just fixed all typos and stuff ;) try again now

Comment: Works perfect but still the dialog.ShowModalUtility() doesn't compile.

Comment: p.s. if I want list of shortcuts and not just one, would it still work¿

Comment: @SagiZiv what do you mean it doesn't compile? Which Unity Version are you using? This is the [API Link](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/EditorWindow.ShowModalUtility.html) it compiles for me ;) Note though that for a build this has to be in a folder called `Editor` or wrapped by `#if UNITY_EDITOR` pre-processors. A list will be a bit tricky .. you will need to change how you set them (how you invoke the `ShowDialog` and handle the result). But why a list anyway?

Comment: I am using Unity 2018.3.14f1, and in the example in your link they use ShowUtility()

And I need a list because I have multiple shortcuts

Comment: @SagiZiv yeah the example is stupid since the method is called `ShowModalUtility`. It exists only in the LTS versions `2017.4`, `2018.4` and `2019.2` and `2019.3` seems to be renamed. Yes I guess you can basically use [`ShowUtility`](https://docs.unity3d.com/2018.3/Documentation/ScriptReference/EditorWindow.ShowUtility.html) as well. Multiple shortcuts should be stored individually ... How are you going to check later or define which shortcut belongs to which action?

Comment: My original plan was to create script that stores a shortcut and a UnityEvent which is the action to perform.
I guess I can store them in separate class instances instead of a list

Comment: @SagiZiv yeah makes sense actually. But as said you would definitely have to somehow extend the scripts above in order to control for which element you call the dialog and how you handle the result after the dialog

Comment: Yeah, well I believe I would find something, but this is a great start. Thank you very much for your time and help